# Homothety and rotation with different centers

Tags: geometry

Is it true that the composition between a homothety and a rotation with different centers can be viewed as a composition between a homothety and a rotation having the same center? (in the plane)

More precise: Is is true that, for any $O_1, O_2$ in the plane and $\forall k\in\mathbb{R}^*, \alpha\in [0,2\pi)$ there exists a point $O$ in the plane and $k'\in\mathbb{R}^*$ and $\alpha'\in [0,2\pi)$ such that:

$$H(O_1;k)\circ R(O_2;\alpha)=H(O;k')\circ R(O;\alpha')$$???

where by: $H(O_1;k)$ I mean the homothety with center $O_1$ and ratio $k$, and by $R(O_2;\alpha)$ I mean the counter-clockwise rotation with respect to $O_2$ with angle $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AB$ be any two points in the plane and $A'B'$ their images after the transformation $H(O_1;k)\circ R(O_2;\alpha)$ has been applied. Let then $\alpha'$ be the counterclockwise angle between vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{A'B'}$, and set $k'=A'B'/AB$.

The locus of points $R$ such that $RA'/RA=k$ is a circle having $PQ$ as diameter, where $P$ and $Q$ are those points on line $AA'$ such that $PA'/PA=QA'/QA=k$. The locus of points $S$ such that $\angle ASA'=\alpha'$ is an arc of circle with endpoints $A$ and $A'$.

This arc intersects the circle at some point $O$, because $A'$ is inside the circle while $A$ is outside (or the other way around). You can check that transformation $H(O;k')\circ R(O;\alpha')$ carries $AB$ to $A'B'$.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you also prove that you will get the same point O for every pair of points A and B ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош You are right: my answer is very partial. I'll think about that.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош I think this answer can be easily improved. Just observe that the above construction also works if we replace $B$ with any other point $P$ of the plane, obtaining the same point $O$, because we always have $\alpha'=\alpha$ and $k'=k$. Hence any point of the plane is carried to its image by $H(O;k')\circ R(O;\alpha')$.